# User has Problems when sharing Unity project with Git

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

Trying to open a Unity project that's being worked on by multiple people and I am encountering what I believe are Git issues. After I open the freshly cloned project, almost all objects are gray. I also have to bake an existing navmesh again because it's broken.

I thought this is a mac vs pc issue. tried on another mac and have the same issue but one of the other team members tried on their mac and it worked ok.

- Read online about what seem to be similar problems that were caused by line endings and tried setting git config `--global core.autocrlf false` or `git config --global core.autocrlf input`
- Tried removing the  .gitattributes file based on the discussion here https://gist.github.com/nemotoo/b8a1c3a0f1225bb9231979f389fd4f3f. The .gitattributes file was added with the latest changes to our project and everything was working ok before. The main change was switching to URP.

Something is corrupting some of the project files I think, because when I clone the repo I see `modified:   Assets/New Terrain.asset`, without making any changes. The main change was switching to URP.

Comment: check "gray" files content in any text editor. or compare the size with your teammates. it can be an lfs isue.

Comment: I'd also like to know if lfs is in use or not. Then again if lfs is configured on your box. And don't guess. If one config change didn't do it, revert it. Document (write down) both the rationale before the change, the change, the rationale after the change and then what you did revert. Fresh checkout, go over. One step after the other. Trouble-shooting with a shotgun, sometimes work thought.

Comment: It was `git lfs`! thank you so much.